# Placing views and elements within Scroll View

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uiscrollview

So I'm trying to get a layout to work using Scroll View.

Correct me if I'm wrong but from what I've been reading around the internet, it looks like to properly use Scroll Views and make it work with AutoLayout you need to have your root view, then put the scroll view inside it with constraints binding it to take the whole size of the root view (left/right/top/bottom constraints to 0) and then adding a view inside the scroll view and once again binding it to take up the whole space.

Afterwards, any ui elements or subviews would go in the innermost view.

My problem is that often I have experienced issues while settings my constraints within the scroll view where for example setting a trailing constraint to 0 wouldn't actually set to the end and so on, the numbers just wouldn't add up. In this case when I'm trying to make the innermost view take the whole space,it ends up messing it up more than anything; see image below.

[image: Storyboard]
[image: Hierarchy]

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just created this layout using the follow:

[image: View of layout]

To test it, I added an image view to the content view and put a humongous image in it. It scrolls around quite nicely including bounce etc.

**Update: You need to select your ViewController and uptick "Adjust Scroll View Insets"**

Hope this helps.

Comment: I tried mimicking the setup that you took a screenshot of with the constraints ( which I maybe didn't setup properly ) and when I do so I end up getting a structure error saying "Missing Constraint - Need constraints for: Y position or height". I tried letting Xcode adding the missing constraint automatically but when I run it the scroll view doesn't appear to be taking up the whole space, there's a white padding on top

Comment: Edit: i posted photos on this link: http://imgur.com/a/CWxyO  you can see how on the layout it's set to have it at the top completely but when it's run there's a white gap. If i want something to actually be placed at the top when running, I have to lay it out literally under than navigation bar in the storyboard for it to work

Comment: Can you provide the source project somewhere for download?

Comment: I've setup a sample github repo and included a sample view controller that I've made that shows the issue I was having where Xcode would tell me that I have missing constraints. The second view controller is the one that shows the blank space on the top. Repository : https://github.com/DimitreBogdanov/testproject

Comment: Sent you a pull request

Comment: I merged in your pull request but as I mentioned before, if you look at the first tab you can see that there is a white padding on top which I'm not sure how to get rid of, I need to be able to work with navigation bars.

Comment: Ahhhh....I see what the problem is. You're seeing the background of the Root view when it first loads, as in the ScrollView is not pinned to the top

Comment: Select your ViewController in IB, and untick "Adjust Scroll View Insets". Problem solved. Pull request sent. :-)

Comment: I think that's exactly what I was looking for!